# Which sentence is correct and how to use dass

Tags: conjunction, conjugation, declension

The first sentence was something a friend posted and it confused me, so I asked her why she wrote it like that while also posting mine, however I haven't got an answer yet, so I thought I'd ask here. Which one is correct if either and why? Also, how do you use *dass*, I don't really understand that yet.

> Friend: Ich hoffe dass euch ein schönen Tag habt.
>
> Me: Ich hoffe dass euch einen schönen Tag haben.

Comment: Both sentences are wrong because *euch* is wrong here ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oh, you realize that each of you used *two* clauses?

One main clause (V2 = verb in 2nd position), one subordinate clause (verb at the end):

> [Ich hoffe], dass [ihr einen schönen Tag habt].

So to clear up your case confusion, we consider the second clause only: The pronoun *ihr* is the *subject*, hence *nominative*. The verb follows the subject, i.e. 2nd plural = habt.

To expand this a bit: If the second clause would *stand alone*, it would have to be a main clause and the word order would shift back to:

> Ihr habt einen schönen Tag.

The *dass* connects both sentences and is called "Konjunktion". Explaining the use of *dass* would be too much here (one question per post only, please), but [canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Objekt/dass-Satz.html) would be a place to start, if your German is good enough (which I assume from reading your post).

Comment: This actually cleared everything up. Thank you for explaining this!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the use of dass - and it's counterpart with a single 's', das:

It may help you to memorise that, when used in a clause in a sentence, 'das' means 'which' and 'dass' means '(so) that'.

Even back then, learning it in school, the rule we were taught was "if you can replace 'das/dass' with 'damit' then it's the 2-s/scharfes s form".

Therefore in your example, translate it as

> I hope (so) that you have a good day.

A counter-example would be:

> Das Abenteuer, das nicht enden will.
>
> The adventure which just won't end.

Note that in both cases you would generally put a comma in front of the 'das' or 'dass'.